# How to capture the logs in zipkins in springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-data, trace, zipkin

How to capture the logs of a springboot application in zipkins?

Answer (score 2):

Zipkin is not meant to be a log capturing or Log aggregator service. The whole purpose of Zipkin is to have your application export Trace and Span Ids to Zipkin Service and then, Zipkin can use this information to display certain things like the Flow of your Service Request among different Micro services and the time taken by each service.

**Step 1:**

You can include the '***spring-cloud-starter-zipkin***' dependency in your spring boot application.Your Application will start generating Trace and Span Ids on this inclusion [you might need to tweak your log config as well]

**Step2:**

Configure the below property in your Spring Boot application properties.

spring.zipkin.base-url=http://********:****/

This will enable your application to export the Trace and Span Ids to Zipkin server.